# Is there a way to thoroughly jumble training and test data to an RNN in Tensorflow / Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I’m not new to neural networks, but I’m new to RNN’s.  Here’s a close analogue of a problem that I’m trying to model using some kind of unidirectional, recurrent neural network.  I believe that the exact architecture is unimportant (I expect to use an LSTM).  What is important to me is how I will select training, validation, and test subsets.  It doesn’t appear that Tensorflow / Keras are set up to do what I want out of the box.

Suppose that we have the following sentence:

> I don’t want to go to the movies unless you come along with me.

Right-truncated versions of this complete sentence may also be complete sentences; or, they may not.  As each individual word comes in, I want to mark what has been seen so far as a complete or incomplete sentence.  So if complete = 1 and incomplete = 0, the sentence above should yield this output sequence:

0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1.

I will have hundreds of sequences in my problem, of variable lengths.

The LSTM examples I’ve been studying on-line typically show the **early** parts of a time series being used as training data, and the **latter** parts being used for validation / test data.  I don’t think this is appropriate for my case.  I am interested in early data being represented in the validation and test sets as well.  This isn’t exactly a standard time-series prediction problem, where we're trying to lock on to a pattern, and predict the next value.  However, the history clearly matters; and the amount of history that matters can vary.

In order to produce the model output, I must run the full RNN in sequence, start to finish, even though I care only about gapped subsets of that output.

I want to choose selected (but fixed) elements of the output in a training step, possibly by using Numpy-style [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).  So during a training step I would throw the validation and test elements away, even though I have generated them.  When I circle back around to perform a test step, I would again run the full RNN, start to finish, but then select a different subset of elements.

I am currently reading through https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/ and https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/.  It may be possible to do what I want.  However, if someone knows of the existence of examples which do exactly what I’m describing, I would greatly appreciate a shortcut.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to shuffle the training data is following format will be:

```
#training_data.append([data, class_num])

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)
```

Will shuffle the data fully

Try this documentation might help:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Rushil Verma.  I know I wrote a lot.  Here is the complication: "In order to produce the model output, I must run the full RNN in sequence, start to finish, even though I care only about gapped subsets of that output."  I need to mask arrays, or delete rows, on each iteration of a training loop.  I am considering various strategies to accomplish this goal, none of them simple.